# Capacitor Derating vs Impedance Curve

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, bypass-capacitor

I need to find a ceramic cap to bypass certain freq on the power plane.  Since voltage can affect the capacitance (voltage derating), and if we consider the impedance vs freq curve (V-shaped curve), does it mean the SRF of the same cap will shift as the voltage varies?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will.

A 10 % variation in capacitance will give about a 5 % variation in SRF [because the resonant frequency depends on sqrt(L.C)]

Comment: These caps could be used as varicap diodes that are not diodes .